# ComboAnalyzer - AttributeImpl not found in AttributeSource

Tags: java, lucene

The analyzer `OpenNLPAnalyzer` based on `OpenNLPTokenizer` in the opennlp package that ships with Lucene in [this blog post](https://fabian-kostadinov.github.io/2018/09/08/introduction-to-lucene-opennlp-part1/) works as promised. I am now trying to use it inside an `ComboAnalyzer` (a part of an ES-plugin to combine multiple analyzers; see link below) in the following way:

```
ComboAnalyzer analyzer = new ComboAnalyzer(new EnglishAnalyzer(), new OpenNLPAnalyzer());
TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("fieldname", new StringReader(text));
```

`stream` is a `ComboTokenStream`. On calling `stream.incrementToken()`, I get the following exception at [line 105 here](https://github.com/SentiOne/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ComboTokenStream.java#L106):

```
Exception in thread "main": State contains AttributeImpl of type org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttributeImpl that is not in in this AttributeSource
```

[Here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/core/org/apache/lucene/util/AttributeSource.html#restoreState-org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeSource.State-) is what the called method `restoreState` does.

```
public final void restoreState(State state) {
    if (state == null)  return;

    do {
        AttributeImpl targetImpl = attributeImpls.get(state.attribute.getClass());
        if (targetImpl == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("State contains AttributeImpl of type " +
                    state.attribute.getClass().getName() + " that is not in in this AttributeSource");
        }
        state.attribute.copyTo(targetImpl);
        state = state.next;
    } while (state != null);
}
```

This hints that one of the `TokenStream`s has an `OffsetAttribute` but the other does not. Is there a clean way to fix this?

I tried to add the line `addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class)` in the same file [here](https://github.com/SentiOne/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/blob/0deefdb95ee75e88fcf02277455efb0b58bd9e3f/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ComboTokenStream.java#L62). I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
Tokenizer source = new OpenNLPTokenizer(
                    AttributeFactory.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY, sentenceDetectorOp, tokenizerOp);
```

The fix is to pass in `TokenStream.DEFAULT_TOKEN_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY` instead of `AttributeFactory.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY`. The former uses `PackedTokenAttributeImpl` for implementing `OffsetAttribute` (and many other attributes) and the latter picks `OffsetAttributeImpl`.